# Casting, Assignability and custom conversions

Tags: .net, vb.net, casting, type-conversion

Consider the following code, simply a class with a custom widening conversion from Long (`Int64`).

```
Public Class CharacterArgs
    Private _CharacterID As Long

    Public ReadOnly Property CharacterID() As Long
        Get
            Return _CharacterID
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal characterID As Long)
        _CharacterID = characterID
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Overloads Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal source As Long) As CharacterArgs
        Return New CharacterArgs(source)
    End Operator

End Class
```

The following code works:

```
Dim test As CharacterArgs
test = 10
```

But:

```
Dim canAssign = GetType(CharacterArgs).IsAssignableFrom(GetType(Long)) 'False
Dim convertTest = Convert.ChangeType(10L, GetType(CharacterArgs))
'Throws InvalidCastException
```

So my questions:

1. Is there a casting/conversion method that supports the custom conversion, but also accepts the destination type as a `System.Type` object (as opposed to `CType`)?
2. Is there a reflection or casting "test" method, similar to `IsAssignableFrom`, that will account for the custom conversion as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far as I know, neither of the things you are looking for exist.  The closest I can think of for the first requirement would be a [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx).  However, TypeConverters seem geared toward designer support and are specific to a single type that will always be either the source or destination type.

To find the conversion methods on a type, you could make a function to look for methods with the special names `op_Implicit` and `op_Explicit` (as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229032.aspx)) on either the source or destination types with the appropriate arguments and return types.

As an aside, the reason `IsAssignableFrom` returns false in this case is that it checks if one type can be *assigned* a variable of another type directly *without* conversions.  Conversion operators add confusion to this issue because in the source code it *appears* that you are doing a simple assignment, but you are actually calling a method and assigning its result.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you are attempting to accomplish with your class, you may be better off using Extension Methods rather than Widening. You can get more information on [Extension Methods in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx).